# How do I get the value of option inside of a range input

Tags: html, jquery, forms, input, range

I been looking around, but still can't find my answer. I want to get all the options from a range input, the input set up is depend on what the end user put in, but only number.

In the example: Min is 1, Max is 10, so the whole list of option is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 <-- is there a way I can find this list? How to look it up on jquery?

```html
<input name="somename" min="1" max="10" step="1" type="range" class="slideThumb">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "list" of ranges, but you can calculate it yourself:

```js
function getRangeList(el)
{
  const min = ~~el.min,
        max = ~~el.max,
        step = ~~el.step,
        list = [];

  for (let i = min; i <= max; i += step)
    list[list.length] = i;

  return list;
}

const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="somename"]');
console.log(getRangeList(inputElement));
```

```html
<input name="somename" min="1" max="10" step="1" type="range" class="slideThumb">
```

Note, if no max specified it will return an empty array, because it means no limit.